# Prevent multiple instances of toastr on same page

Tags: jquery, toastr

Is there a way to prevent toastr from displaying multiple instances of the same message on a single page. I am using one page to cater to my add and update functions. Here is a snippet of my code

```js
window.toastr.options = {
          "toastClass": "toast-success-create-campaign",
          "closeButton": false,
          "debug": false,
          "newestOnTop": true,
          "progressBar": false,
          "positionClass": "toast-top-center",
          "onclick": null,
          "showDuration": "300",
          "hideDuration": "1000",
          "timeOut": "5000",
          "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
          "showEasing": "swing",
          "hideEasing": "linear",
          "showMethod": "fadeIn",
          "hideMethod": "fadeOut",
          "maxOpened":1,
          "preventOpenDuplicates": true
}

$('.btn-add').on('click',function(){
  window.toastr.success('Add Called','Success!');
})

$('.btn-update').on('click',function(){
  window.toastr.success('Update Called','Success!');
})
```

It seems that toastr is keeping a cache of all toast calls which is why when I try to execute the function it goes on top of each other instead of displaying just one. How do I modify my code in order to get my desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `preventOpenDuplicates` is not supported on the native-JavaScript version of Toastr, it is only supported in [angular-toastr](https://github.com/Foxandxss/angular-toastr/blob/2264a9abdfaaf89ba770b978de13e42843cc5306/README.md#toastr-customization).

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr/blob/master/toastr.js), the text `Open` isn't even contained there.
There is a pull request ([Prevent duplicate #568](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr/issues/568)) asking to add support for `preventOpenDuplicates`, but it is not merged and there is no comment.